# Excel: How to match substring to another string and return the matched result?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

When doing data dump for time log activities, the data comes out to simply the name of activities in one column and a string of one or multiple labels in another column (column B in image).

Then I do have a separate sheet that has an identifier of what some of those labels means. Column G is the individual labels and Column H is their meaning.

I can do a check to see if a string in B contains a label in G and return TRUE or FALSE, but I also need to return the first match if anything. Is there a way to do that?

Example: in B, "horse dog" has a match of "dog" in G. Can I return the value "Bean" to this match somehow?

[Sample Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bQQUP.png)

Comment: How about "bird cat dog"? Return the result: Bean Satan??

Comment: Dog will match first so a return of Bean is needed. Although returning both hit is also ok.